# What is "Navy Die"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw a student allergy list, and it said "Sorbitol, Navy Die, Dust". Could someone tell me what is "Navy Die"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe they meant "Navy /dye/"...?

Comment: Yeah, almost certainly they meant "dye".

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a typo. "Navy dye" was what they meant.

Navy dye allergy is a relatively common one that is usually noticed when blue jeans start causing rashes or irritation. I believe this falls under [textile dermatitus](http://dermnetnz.org/dermatitis/textile-dermatitis.html), where someone is allergic to the dye(s) used in textiles.

Comment: Off-topic, but is "*type-o*" accepted usage? I've only ever seen *typo* (which I presume is short for "typographical error").

Comment: @atkins I changed it to typo since that seems to be more common. Some places say that type-o means type O blood but [others](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Type-o) say it means typographical error.